# Adjust percentage in nested divs so it fits a 12 cols system

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I have the following site structure that fits a 12 col system using flexbox:

[image]

It's basically a menu, sidebar and content type of site. The width of an individual column in the 12 col system is 8.3333%. Inside the content div there are two nested `content-left` and `content-right` divs.

My question is, is it possible to set the `flex-basis` property of the `content-left` and `content-right` divs so they fit exactly in the 12 col system (the `content-right` div starts where the Projects menu item starts)?

As much as I'm trying, I don't seem to get it right. For example, setting `.content-left { flex-basis: 25% }` and `.content-right { flex-basis: 50% }` doesn't get the desired results, because these divs are nested inside the content div which measures 75%, not 100% of the width.

Any help would be appreciated.

**PHP:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Projects</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="sidebar">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="content-left">
                </div>
                <div class="content-right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.page {
    max-width: 1440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu ul {
    display: flex;
}

.menu li {
    flex-basis: 25%;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
    flex-basis: 25%;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 75%;
}

.content-left {
    flex-basis: ???%;
}

.content-right {
    flex-basis: ???%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `1/3` and `2/3` (9 columns that you will divide into 3 and 6)

```css
.page {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
  padding:0;
}

.menu li {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  list-style:none;
  outline:1px solid red;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  background:pink;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 75%;
  height:50px
}

.content-left {
  flex-basis: calc(1/3 * 100%);
  background:red;
}

.content-right {
  flex-basis: calc(2/3 * 100%);
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Projects</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="content-left">
      </div>
      <div class="content-right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```